# Why doesn't use warnings FATAL => 'all' seem to work?

Tags: perl, warnings, mod-perl, apache2.2

This script:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

warn 'warning';
die 'death';
```

...results in 'warning' getting logged, but doesn't die at that point, instead dying with 'death'.

I have a mod_perl module that overrides `$main::SIG{__DIE__}` to basically spit out die() messages to the browser during development, but it does not touch `SIG{__WARN__}`, so what is happening here?

This is on perl 5.10.1 on Windows Server 2003, with "-w" in PerlSwitches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You misunderstood the purpose of the [`warnings` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html#Fatal-Warnings). It is there to emit a warning message for completely legal, but possibly wrong operations. Example:

```
use warnings;
my ($x, $y) = ("hello", "world");
say "same" if $x == $y;
```

→ `Argument "world" isn't numeric…`. We can make certain categories produce fatal errors with `use warnings FATAL => $CATEGORY` with categories like `numeric` or `uninitialized`. The `all` category represents all categories.

It *does not* change the semantics of every `warn` to `die`. You can do this yourself, e.g. with overriding a `local $SIG{__WARN__}`, or creating a `warn` function that does `croak @_`. You can even override `CORE::GLOBAL::warn` to change all `warn`s, even if they are in other modules.

The [`CGI::Carp`](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aCarp) module has a `warningsToBrowser` option; you may want to look at the source code to see how it's implemented.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't *seem* to work because your test isn't testing what you want to test. Try this:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

print undef;
die 'death';
```

Just as a `no warnings` will not prevent `warn` from working, `warnings FATAL` will not make `warn` die.